# How do I reach the patent holder?

Tags: wo2008070594a3

I would like to contact the patent holder(issuer) to discuss the patent but I don't know how to find him. I have done extensive Google search and found a few phone numbers that lead to the same name and location but only one number works and it has not been answered for the past week that I have tried. What is the best way to reach the patent holder?

Answer (score 1):

The US application that relates to this is **not** a granted patent. By way of teaching you how to fish rather than giving you a fish: You can go to the USPTO Public PAIR web site and with the US application number you can look this up. You will find that the US application has gone abandoned for lack of a timely response. If you still need to reach the inventors it looks there is a name address and phone number for the patent practitioner he hired.